# Code that Parses through Pseudo Code for Big O Analysis

Tags: java, parsing, time-complexity, big-o, analysis

I'm currently trying to code a program that reads pseudo code from a txt file and outputs the Big O notation for the pseudo code as a new txt file. I'm struggling to find a way to parse through the for loops for the key information needed to find the time complexity of the code. For example:

```
"input02.txt"
n m /* The estimate variable */
i j /* The control variable in the for loop */
tmp x j /* Variable(s) appeared in the loop body */
for (i=0; i<n*m; i*=2) {
   for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
      tmp = tmp + 3;
      x--;
      j++;
   }
}
"input02_BigO.txt"
O( n * log(n*m) )
```

To try and simplify what I'm asking for, here's the description of the project I was assigned to do:

Description: 
Write a program to analyze nested Java’ "for" loops and provide the Big-O notation estimate for the provided code given in the input file. In particular, the input file contains the nested "for" loops in an appropriate Java syntax, and is limited to (1) at most 2 "for" loops and “for” loops only (so no "while" or "do-while" loops) (2) simple operations + (plus), - (minus), * (multiplication) and / (division). Note that shorthanded operations "++", "--", "+=", "-=", "=", and "/=" are also allowed. For the sake of simplicity, you can assume that the input code is under Java language and is free of syntax errors, as well as no methods/functions involved.

Input/Output: 
Input File ".txt" is a text file where the first three lines describe different set of variable. Line #1 describes the estimate variables which should be used in the BigO estimate outcome. Line #2 describes the control variables in each loop. Line #3 describes variables appeared in the loop/nested loop body. Output Write to file "_BigO.txt" the Big-O estimate of the code given in file named ".txt". If you cannot give the estimate, explain in that file the reasons.

Example: 
shown above

What I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Big_O_Analysis {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        /* ASKS USER TO INPUT NAME OF TXT FILE TO BE READ */
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter file name (without '.txt': ");

        /* STORES FILE NAME TO READ INPUT FILE AND CREATE OUTPUT FILE*/
        String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
        String inputFile = fileName + ".txt";
        String outputFile = fileName + "_BigO.txt";

        /* READS INPUT FILE AND ANALYZES FOR LOOPS AND ASSIGNMENT STATEMENTS */
        File file = new File(inputFile);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        String line = input.nextLine();
        String[] complexity = new String[10];                                   // Holds time complexity
        while (input.hasNext())                                                 // Search for line with for loop
        {
            while (!line.startsWith("for"))
            {
                line = input.nextLine();
            }

            // PARSE THROUGH LOOP
            String[] forLoop = line.split(";");                                 // Splits loop into 3 parts by the ';', ex: "for (i=0", "i<10","i++)"

            // Keeps control variable part of for loop
            String[] forLoopStart = forLoop[0].split("(");                      // Splits "for (i=0" into "for " and "i=0"
            String initialization = forLoopStart[1];                            // Stores the start of the for loop "i=0"
            char control = initialization.charAt(0);                            // Stores control variable 'i'
            int start = Integer.parseInt(initialization.substring(2));          // Stores start value of control '0'


            // Keeps estimate variables
            String termination = forLoop[1].substring(2);                       // Stores termination of loop. "i<10" -> "10" or "i<n" -> "n" or "i<n*m" -> "n*m"
            int end;                                                            // Initializes termination value for loop 
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<termination.length(); i++)                        // Gets termination value when it is a number: "i<10"
            {
                index++;
            }
            end = Integer.parseInt(termination);


            // Keeps increment values
            String increment = forLoop[2].substring(0,forLoop[2].length()-1);   // Stores increment section of loop. "i++)" -> "i++" or "i+=10" or "i*=i"
            String inc = increment.substring(1,3);                              // Stores increment. "++", "*=", etc
            if (inc == "++" || inc == "--")
                complexity[1] = termination;
            else if(inc == "*=" || inc == "/=")                                 // Log
                complexity[1] = "log(" + termination + ")";
            else if (inc == "+=" || inc == "-=")                                // Jump
                complexity[1] = termination + "/" + increment.substring(3);


            String factor = "";                                                 // Stores factor of increment. "2", "10", "n"
            boolean factorDigits = false;                                       // The following boolean values test to see if the factor is just a number, variable by itself, or variable with number
            boolean factorVar = false;
            boolean factorMix = false;
            int fac;                                                            // If factor is just a number
            for (int i = 3; i<increment.length(); i++)
            {
                if (Character.isDigit(increment.charAt(i)))
                    factorDigits = true;
                else if (Character.isLetter(increment.charAt(i)))
                    factorVar = true;
            }
            if (factorDigits == true && factorVar == false)
            {
                factor = factor + increment.substring(3);
                fac = Integer.parseInt(factor);
            }
            else if (factorDigits == false && factorVar == true)
            {
                factor = factor + increment.substring(3);
            }
            else if (factorDigits == true && factorVar == true)
            {
                factorMix = true;
                factor = factor + increment.substring(3);
            }




            // Reads for assignment statements
            line = input.nextLine();
            int assignments = 0;
            while (input.hasNext() && !line.startsWith("for"))
            {
                assignments++;
                line = input.nextLine();
            }
            complexity[0]= Integer.toString(assignments);

            // Analyzes loop


        }

        /* FORMS COMPLEXITY */
        String timeComplexity = "";

        /* FORMS COMPLEXITY INTO BIG O NOTATION */
        String bigO = "O(" + timeComplexity + ")";

        /* CREATES AND WRITES A FILE OF THE BIG O ESTIMATE */
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outputFile);
        output.print(bigO);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if the pseudocode contains an infinite loop? Please update question to include as that is quite important.

Comment: I edited the post to show what I have tried so far. Just not sure if I'm heading in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: It says,  "parse a Java program.... "   You can spend forever trying to make a bad ad hoc parser and it will give you nothing but grief.  Why don't you dump the parsing problem in somebody else, and just get a working Java parser?  There's a bunch out there, including one for ANTLR.  (We have a commercial one but you don't want that for a homework assignment).  Then you can concentrate on collecting the information needed for your big-Oh assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This will be tricky quite tricky, even when parsing is solved :)

If you want to do it properly, you could use a StreamTokenizer for tokenization and build a recursive descent parser for the whole language on top.

Alternatively, you could make some additional assumption and handle blocks on a line by line basis. In this case, you could get extract the loop initializer, condition and increment to "parts" using this snippet:

```
 if (line.startsWith("for") {
   int cut0 = line.indexOf('(');
   int cut1 = line.lastIndexOf(')');
   String parts = line.substring(cut0+1, cut1).split(";");
   ...
```

Depending on how sophisticated you want to be you could use a existing expression parser on the parts -- or just verify that they match some assumptions for the cases you are able to handle...